# Parity – unlock multiple accounts at startup

Tags: accounts, parity, parity-wallet

I unlock an account on parity startup using the following arguments:

```
parity
   --unlock $COINBASE \
   --password $CONFIG_DIR/password \
   ...
```

How can I unlock multiple accounts at startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--unlock` expects a comma-delimited list of addresses, e.g.:

```
parity \
  -- unlock $COINBASE,$ACCOUNT3,$ACCOUNT7 \
  -- password $CONFIG_DIR/password \
  ...
```

Note that this implies that the password on all accounts is the same. Hope this helps.

*Disclosure: I work for Parity.*

Comment: What if the password is different for the each account, does it still work? @5chdn♦

Comment: No, you should use the console for that.

Comment: @5chdn What about using the config toml file?  Could you unlock multiple accounts with different passwords in that case?

Comment: Yes, it's working the same way.

Comment: @Afri is there a way to unlock accounts programmatically using json or web3?  It would be better because you could also re-lock them when the transaction is complete.

Comment: @stone212 use `personal_unlockAccount` RPC call